# TreeMap : How to build tree map chart in vega lite

Tags: vega-lite

Transpose : TreeMap / Tree available in Vega but  could not find similar transpose in Vega lite library. If i want to build hierarchical map using vega lite, what are the options ?

I have tried find it in the vega example but could not find any example

Appreciate your help

Comment: Based on this open issue on the Vega-Lite GitHub (https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1872), it seems that treemaps and other force-directed layouts are not currently supported in Vega-Lite, so perhaps sticking with the Vega version may be the best option at this time.